# how to submit form and display result with out refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have this form and result `div` :

```
<form action="result.php">

<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" value="11" />
<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" value="12" />
<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" value="13" />
<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" value="14" />
<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" value="15" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="show result" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Now I want when i click on the submit display `result.php` in `div` with `id="result"`

how can I use ajax for this?

Comment: why do you need ajax for this? whats the context? anyway is too broad and/or unclear

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(form).submit(function(e)
 {
     var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
     var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
     $.ajax(
     {
         url : formURL,
         type: "POST",
         data : postData,
         success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
         {
             $("#result").html(data);
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
         {
              console.log('error');      
         }
     });
     e.preventDefault(); 
     e.unbind(); 
});
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Add an id attribute on your form and then use ajax like the following:

```
$('#form-id').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = $('#form-id').serialize();

   $.ajax({
      type:    'POST',
      url:     'result.php',
      data:    data,
      success: function(data) {
         $('#result').html(data);
      }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for it. You can cycle through the inputs to collect the data for ajax call. if ajax returns successful answer, then change the div#result inner contents with the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="javascript:;">
```

replace form tag like this

```
$('#submit').submit(function(){
 formData = $('form').serialize();   
 $.ajax({ url:'result.php',
    dataType:'text',
    data:formData,

    success:function(data){
      $('#result').html(data);
    }
    });
});
```